# Issue z-index css

Tags: css

I have an issue with my css, when I log in or sign out, I have a message that displayed. The issue is that the text is displayed behind another button, to try to solve this, I thought that I could add a `z-index` an set it to around 20 to be sure it will be over everything but when I applied it, nothing happend and I don't know why. Here is the `CSS` code:

```
.alert-success {
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
  color: #3c763d;
}
.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

and 2 photos for you. [image]

Comment: `z-index` doesn't apply unless the element has a `position` property of something *other* than `static`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` only applies to *positioned* elements, and yours are not.

Set a `position` value other than `static` (you likely want `relative` as it has the fewest side effects).

Answer (score 1):

z-index specifies the stack order of an element but z-index only works for positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).
Element with greater z-index would always be in front of element with lower z-index.